# Trouble building multi-project .sln via command line

Tags: command-line, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2005

Also seems the documentation is somewhat conflicted.

`devenv /?` :

```
/Project        Specifies the project to build, clean, or deploy.
                Must be used with /Build, /Rebuild, /Clean, or /Deploy.
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z(VS.80).aspx :

```
Devenv SolutionName /build SolnConfigName [/project ProjName [/projectconfig ProjConfigName]]
```

Arguments

*SolutionName*

**Required**. The full path and name of the solution file.

*SolnConfigName*

**Required**. The name of the solution configuration that will be used to build the solution named in SolutionName.

*/project ProjName*

**Optional**. The path and name of a project file within the solution. You can enter a relative path from the SolutionName folder to the project file, or the project's display name, or the full path and name of the project file.

---

If I run `devenv "C:\[PATH]\[SINGLE-PROJECT-SOLUTION].sln" /rebuild "Release|Win32"` it works fine (no `/project`) however if I run the same command with a different solution that has multiple projects, it fails with:

```
The selected file is not a valid solution file.
The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error
```

Is it possible to run a single command to build a multi-project solution via command line in VS2005? *(Ideally with parallelization)*

Comment: *The selected file is not a valid solution file.* does the solution open/build in VS? Also what happens if you just use msbuild /path/to/my.sln ?

Comment: Yup. I get this with MSBuild v4: `Solution file error MSB5010: No file format header found.`

Comment: Alright ignore that message. In my attempts to get `devenv` working, at least one command ended up re-writing the `.sln` to some .xml nonsense. Now I'm getting a prompt that `msbuild.exe` couldn't find `vcbuild.exe` and to add it to the system path. I'll try that.

Comment: So the `MSBuild.exe`/`VCBuild.exe` method actually parses the first project correctly and starts a build however it fails to find `winsock2.h` from the `.pch`. Pretty sure the project builds on it's own so not sure what's going on here. Do I need to pass additional parameters?

Comment: Sorry no idea, also don't have VS2005 anymore to test..